# How do linux-kernel schedule processes with weight value?

Tags: linux-kernel

I am reading "Linux Kernel Development" and I don't understand weight value of process. In linux kernel, each process has a nice value, and then mapping nice value to weight.

- I think weight is "the proportion of processor time". it mean process'runtime allocated is: its weight/(total weight of all process)* (processor time). if result of above formula is 10%, but actual the runtime of process lower than 10%, it is priority. Right?
- I'm confused about how cfs check it. Does cfs check periodly (e.g. 1 milisecond) and update runtime of process, compare the proportion of actual runtime/process'runtime allocated with the chosen minimum and run it ? By the way, can you list some function used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the function `set_load_weight` in linux kernel source. Here, the actual load of a scheduling entity(task/group of tasks) is calculated. This routine gets called from different places(e.g fork, or when you set a new nice value from user space, etc).

```
if (update_load && p->sched_class == &fair_sched_class) {
    reweight_task(p, prio);
} else {
    load->weight = scale_load(sched_prio_to_weight[prio]);
    load->inv_weight = sched_prio_to_wmult[prio];
}
```

`sched_prio_to_weight` contains the weight according to priority.

The structure that saves the weight information for a task is `struct load_weight`. This structure is used by cfs to get the load of an entity and update the runtime(`vruntime`) of a task in the routine `update_curr`.
cfs selects next task to run in `pick_next_task`. Below is the code snippet.

```
for_each_class(class) {
        p = class->pick_next_task(rq, prev, rf);
        if (p) {
            if (unlikely(p == RETRY_TASK))
                goto again;
            return p;
        }
    }
```

Here, it traverses each scheduling class and checks for a task to run.